# Does Logic Pro support Rewire 64-bit (for Reason 6)?

Tags: logic-pro, mac, system

Assuming that Logic Pro is in itself 64-bit compatible, does it also support ReWire in 64-bit mode so that Reason 6 can be used with it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know to date, rewire doesn't support 64 bit, but you can have Logic run in 32 bit to get around that problem by going to logic in your applications folder; right click; get info; check the box that says run at 32 bit.

Comment: +1 for simple explanation of how to switch an application to 32 bit mode, which is the best solution to any 32/64 bit issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rewire does support 64bit but the Host application must implement it. I'm not sure if apple has updated Logic to run rewire in 64bit mode if not then as the other user stated you can run logic in 32bit mode as instructed.